# OpenCart 1.5 - Admin username is autofilling across store are in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opencart, vqmod, opencart-module

We use OpenCart 1.5+ and find that our saved Admin username autofills into the search box on the shop side. Also does this on other form data.

This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

I have seen a VQMod being implemeted to help prevent this, any other ideas on how to fix

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with a VQmod

```
<file name="/catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <input type="password" style="display:none;" /><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```